# failed to open stream: Permission denied - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload a file (image) via REST API using `file_put_contents`. However, it gives the error :- failed to open stream: Permission denied.

I have gone through most of the questions here and tried doing almost everything

- Changing owner to root or apache
- Changing group to root or apache
- Changing permissions to 755 or 777
- Other options too

I'm still not sure what's wrong and some help would be needed.

Here's my code to upload the file.

```
public function tryImage_post(){
        $image = base64_decode($this->input->post("img_front"));
        $image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        $filename = $image_name . '.' . 'png';
        //rename file name with random number
        $path = FCPATH."img/".$filename;
        //image uploading folder path
        file_put_contents($path . $filename, $image);
        // image is bind and upload to respective folde
    }
```

Error message :-

```
<p>Message:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/development/img/8f2e7959de8beb89ba5e304a6e69d894.png8f2e7959de8beb89ba5e304a6e69d894.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied</p>
```

Comment: The filename appears two times, is that intended? Does `/var/www/html/development/img/` exist with the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change the directory permissions,

`chmod -R 777 var/www/html/development/img`

After that, change your code like the following.

```
public function tryImage_post(){
    $image = base64_decode($this->input->post("img_front"));
    $image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $filename = $image_name . '.' . 'png';
    //rename file name with random number
    $path = FCPATH."img/".$filename;
    //image uploading folder path
    file_put_contents($path, $image);
    // image is bind and upload to respective folde
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function tryImage_post(){
    $image = base64_decode($this->input->post("img_front"));
    $image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $filename = $image_name . '.' . 'png';
    //rename file name with random number
    file_put_contents("img/".$filename, $image);
     //image uploading folder path

}
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality to see a community discussion about "Try this" answers.